# Send Mirf values with ethercard

Tags: arduino

I have project where I'm getting data over nRF24L01 and using Mirf to that. Now I'm working for Hub which need to send data to my webservice. For ethernet my choice was ENC28j60 with ethercard library.

Question : How I can wait data from Mirf and just send data forward with Ethercard browseUrl? I can send data without Mirf but there's some loop which I'm not understand.

My code :

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Mirf.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <MirfHardwareSpiDriver.h>
#include <EtherCard.h>

// Set network settings
static byte mymac[] = { 0x74, 0x69, 0x69, 0x2D, 0x30, 0x31 };
byte Ethernet::buffer[700];
static uint32_t timer;
// My webservice
const char website[] PROGMEM = "my.webservice.com";

// Mirf variables
int tmpVal1;

// Local components
const int Yellow = 6;
const int Blue = 5;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);

  // Setup leds
  pinMode(Yellow, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(Yellow, LOW);
  pinMode(Blue, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(Blue, LOW);

  setupMirf();
  setupEthernet();
}

void loop() {

  // Waiting to get date from Mirf
  while (!Mirf.dataReady()) {
   //ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());
  }

  Mirf.getData((byte *)&tmpVal1);
  Serial.print(tmpVal1);
  Serial.println(F(" C"));

  // Receive responses
  ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());

  if (millis() > timer) {
    timer = millis() + 5000;
    //Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Sending data to webservice : ");
    ether.browseUrl(PSTR("/sendingdata.asmx/sendingdata?"), "Device=100&DeviceValue=80", website, my_callback);
  }
  //ShowLedNotification();
}

// called when the client request is complete
static void my_callback (byte status, word off, word len) {
  Serial.println(">>>");
  Ethernet::buffer[off+300] = 0;
  Serial.print((const char*) Ethernet::buffer + off);
  Serial.println("...");
  digitalWrite(Blue,HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(Blue,LOW);
}

void ShowLedNotification() {
    if (tmpVal1 > 0 ) {
    digitalWrite(Yellow, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(Yellow, LOW);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(Blue, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(Blue, LOW);
  }
}


long readVcc() {
  long result;
  // Read 1.1V reference against AVcc
  ADMUX = _BV(REFS0) | _BV(MUX3) | _BV(MUX2) | _BV(MUX1);
  delay(2); // Wait for Vref to settle
  ADCSRA |= _BV(ADSC); // Convert
  while (bit_is_set(ADCSRA,ADSC));
  result = ADCL;
  result |= ADCH<<8;
  result = 1126400L / result; // Back-calculate AVcc in mV
  return result;
}

//Setting up network and getting DHCP IP
void setupEthernet() {
  Serial.println(F("Setting up network and DHCP"));
  Serial.print(F("MAC: "));
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    Serial.print(mymac[i], HEX);
    if (i < 5)
      Serial.print(':');
  }
  Serial.println();

  if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac) == 0)
    Serial.println(F("Failed to access Ethernet controller"));
  Serial.println(F("Setting up DHCP"));
  if (!ether.dhcpSetup())
    Serial.println(F("DHCP failed"));

  ether.printIp("My IP: ", ether.myip);
  ether.printIp("Netmask: ", ether.netmask);
  ether.printIp("GW IP: ", ether.gwip);
  ether.printIp("DNS IP: ", ether.dnsip);

   // Check network connection
  if (!ether.dnsLookup(website))
    Serial.println("DNS failed");
  ether.printIp("SRV: ", ether.hisip);

  }

void setupMirf() {
   //Initialize nRF24
  Serial.println(F("Initializing Mirf"));
  Mirf.spi = &MirfHardwareSpi;
  Mirf.init();
  Mirf.setRADDR((byte *)"serv1");
  Mirf.payload = sizeof(tmpVal1);
  // we use channel 90 as it is outside of WLAN bands
  // or channels used by wireless surveillance cameras
  Mirf.channel = 90;
  Mirf.config();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did get that work. Now using if clause not while Mirf.dataReady()

```
void loop() {

  if (Mirf.dataReady()) {

  Mirf.getData((byte *)&tmpVal1);
  Serial.print(tmpVal1);
  Serial.println(F(" C"));
  ShowLedNotification();

  // Send data to webservice
  if (millis() > timer) {
  timer = millis() + 5000;
  Serial.println("Sending data to webservice");

  String myVarsStr = "Device=";
  myVarsStr += myDeviceID;
  myVarsStr += "&DeviceValue=";
  myVarsStr += tmpVal1;
  char myVarsCh[40];
  myVarsStr.toCharArray(myVarsCh, 40);      

  ether.browseUrl(PSTR("/receivedata.asmx/ReceiveData?"), myVarsCh, website, my_callback);
  }
}
else
{
word pos = ether.packetReceive();
word len = ether.packetLoop(pos);
delay(200);
}
}
```